# StackView in Android 3.0 HoneyComb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, stackview

Can any one provide any example of StackView in Android 3.0 HoneyComb , it wll be a gr8 help for me .. thnxxx....

Answer (score 2):

You can find a very basic tutorial on `StackView` here:

> http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/StackWidget/index.html

Here a sample demonstrating a `StackWidget` using the `StackView`.